# How to do diacritic insensitive matching with NSRegularExpression?

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

Is it possible to perform diacritic insensitive matching using NSRegularExpression? The options for regularExpressionWithPattern doesn't seem to provide this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the diacritics and work on the cleaned string, something like:

```
tmpString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[realString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
```

Comment: Isn't converting to a lossy ASCII conversion and back an overkill way to remove diacritics? Won't this remove far more characters than are needed?

Comment: @rmaddy: He doesn't need to convert it back, the OP just needs matching. This can be done on converted string.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't very clear. You answer converts the original string to an ASCII string with lossy conversion. My point was that this conversion can be too lossy. Any non-latin letters will be lost in the conversion. We don't know what RE the OP is using but there are ways to get a new string that gets rid of diacritics without nearly as much potential loss as your suggested approach. BTW - my comment about "conversion and back" referred to your answer of going from string to data and back to string.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy I was able to do diacritic insensitive string matching with your solution! (And keeping the original string allowed me to display the original in the place of the cleaned text)